# Trying to rendering the options based on json data but getting map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selection, map-function

**I am trying to get a model based on the Brand. But getting the error when selection the next option**

**Error says bikeBrand is not a Function**

**Below is the Json data getting from backend**

```
response from backend { BMW:["F900R", "F900XR"], KTM:["125 Duke", "250 Duke"]}
```

**Then storing on the state using useState hook in React**

```
const [bikeBrands, setBikeBrands] = useState("")
```

**First option value is storing in below hook too**

```
const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState("")
```

**Problem is in the second selection option.**

```
<select onChange={(e) => setSelectedBrand(e.target.value)}>
                        <option>Choose brand</option>
                        {Object.keys(bikeBrands).map((bikeBrand, index) => {
                            return <option>{bikeBrand}</option>
                        })}
                    </select>
                    <select onChange={(e) => setModel(e.target.value)}>
                        <option>Choose Model</option>
                        {Object.keys(bikeBrands).map((bikeBrand, index) => {
                            bikeBrand.map((brandModels, index) => {
                                return <option>{brandModels}</option>
                            })
                        })}

                    </select>
```

Comment: Could you paste the actual error you're receiving? The title states you're getting `map` is not a function` but in your body you're stating you're getting `bikeBrands is not a function` which both have very different meanings.

What is the default state you're setting for bikeBrands? Is it an empty string like you have above? If so, this error is because of that; `.map()` is not a function on strings lilke the error states.

Comment: bikeBrands.map is not a function the error says.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing

```js
{Object.keys(bikeBrands).map((bikeBrand, index) => {
  bikeBrand.map((brandModels, index) => {
   return <option>{brandModels}</option>
  })
})}
```

note that `Object.keys(bikeBrands)` gives you array of keys, and these individual keys (one at a time) are stored in `bikeBrand`.

This `bikeBrand` is a variable which holds string `BMW` or `KTM` not the value.

So instead of writing `bikeBrand.map`

Use `bikeBrands[bikeBrand].map` to access Array values.

Comment: I tried that now there is no error showing but i am also getting the values. {Object.keys(bikeBrands).map((bikeBrand, index) => {
                            bikeBrand === selectedBrand && bikeBrands[bikeBrand].map((brandModels, index) => {
                                return <option>{brandModels}</option>
                            })
                        })}

Comment: I tried to add a condition but still not value get.

Comment: add value attribute in <option> tag

Comment: also add value attribute in select tag [ store the value in `useState`]

Comment: Added too but still the same problem

Comment: can you share code in codesandbox or somwhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241500/discussion-between-akhil-rana-and-harsh-mehta).